# Before insert trigger failing to autofill Title field with the selected Status field value in Salesforce

Tags: apex, before-trigger

So, I have created a trigger which autofills the selected satus value into the title text field in the lead object but I am getting a DML exception. Can someone tell what is wrong in this

> CopyStatusToTitle: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old Trigger.CopyStatusToTitle: line 9, column 1

```
trigger CopyStatusToTitle on Lead (before insert, after insert) {

    List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            //process before insert
              for(Lead l : trigger.New){
                l.Title = l.Status;
                insert l;
            }

        }else if(Trigger.isAfter){
            //process after insert

        }  
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call `insert` explicitly in triggers when executing on the records within the same context, `Lead` in this case. It's left to the platform to do that.

You will need to remove the `insert` call from your trigger.

```
for(Lead l : trigger.New){
    l.Title = l.Status;
    //insert l; // comment this
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and now I am trying to autopoulate the company which is a required field from the selected value of a status i.e         
  for(Lead l : trigger.New){
                l.Company = l.Status;
                insert l;
            }                                                                                                                                        but now since Company field is mandatory to save before saving the record, how can I achieve this without getting an error?

Comment: I still see you are using `insert` here. You don't use `insert` keyword on the current record being processed within the trigger. Also, if you have a separate question with any other issue, please open a new question. The way the SFSE format works is that we limit a question to a [specific issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you , will do so :)